# TSQL - ordering by XML sequence with cross apply

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-order-by, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server, how can I guarantee that returned data is ordered by the sequence of nodes in an XML column, when using `CROSS APPLY` in the following?

```
SELECT MC.Id, MC.Name
FROM MyParent MP
  CROSS APPLY MP.ChildrenXml.nodes('/d/i') AS CX(CX)
  INNER JOIN MyChildren MC
    ON MC.Id = CX.value('text()[1]','int')

-- MyParent table...
ChildrenXML
<d><i>1</i><i>3></i><i>2</i></d>

-- MyChildren table...
Id    Name
1     Tom
2     Richard
3     Harry

-- Expected output...
Id    Name
1     Tom
3     Harry
2     Richard
```

The best I can come up with (but doesn't feel like a great solution) is...

```
; WITH ChildIds AS (
   SELECT CX.value('text()[1]','int') AS Id,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CX.CX) AS RowNum
   FROM MyParent MP
     CROSS APPLY MP.ChildrenXml.nodes('/d/i') AS CX(CX)
)
SELECT MC.Id, MC.Name
FROM ChildIds CI
  INNER JOIN MyChildren MC
    ON MC.Id = CI.Id
ORDER BY CI.RowNum
```

Comment: `CX.value('let $i := . return count(../i[. << $i]) + 1','int')` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b42564bbbff5cf376efb7a04af0a047e

Comment: @Charlieface - sorry, but how is this a duplicate?  That asks for the row-number... I'm specifically asking how to order the data using the specific sequence of the XML.  You can't use `position()` in order-by, and my suggestion already uses the information provided in the answer. This is not a duplicate

Comment: Happy to reopen the question, but once you have the position of the XML nodes, you can order by it. See the fiddle I linked

Comment: @Charlieface - unless I'm missing something, you've taken the query I've already written and changed how RowNum is generated.  I wanted to know if there was a better way (preferably without CTE

Comment: You can do it without a CTE, by putting `.value` into the `ORDER BY` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c70dc65fd45cc241f85c4a70b3fb151 Alternatively leave it in the `SELECT` and you can still `ORDER BY` that value https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93d22596c88d340ce84cac4430d3b99c

Comment: Then can I please ask that you add that as an answer, and undelete the question? I can honestly say I would have never in a million years come up with that solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Charlieface pointed me to the answer I really wanted... although I really appreciate their time/effort with their answer.

I never considered using `ROW_NUMBER` as the `ORDER BY` itself...

```
SELECT MC.Id, MC.Name
FROM MyParent MP
  CROSS APPLY MP.ChildrenXml.nodes('/d/i') AS CX(CX)
  INNER JOIN MyChildren MC
    ON MC.Id = CX.value('text()[1]','int')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CX.CX)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aacc4a1a2006b40a09cbc9e9ca4103ee)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not allow you to use `position()` in a `.value` call.

Instead you can hack it by counting nodes.

You can do it without a CTE, by putting `.value` into the `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT
  CI.Id,
  CI.Name
FROM MyParent MP
CROSS APPLY MP.ChildrenXml.nodes('/d/i') AS CX(CX)
INNER JOIN MyChildren CI
    ON CI.Id = CX.value('text()[1]','int')
ORDER BY CX.value('let $i := . return count(../i[. << $i]) + 1','int')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c70dc65fd45cc241f85c4a70b3fb151)

Alternatively leave it in the `SELECT` and you can still `ORDER BY` that value

```sql
SELECT
  CI.Id,
  CI.Name,
  CX.value('let $i := . return count(../i[. << $i]) + 1','int') RowNumber
FROM MyParent MP
CROSS APPLY MP.ChildrenXml.nodes('/d/i') AS CX(CX)
INNER JOIN MyChildren CI
    ON CI.Id = CX.value('text()[1]','int')
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93d22596c88d340ce84cac4430d3b99c)

The way this works is as follows:

- Assign the current node `.` to `$i`
- Take the parent node `..` and count all its `i` child nodes which...
- ... are `<<` before the `$i` node
- Add one

Comment: Excellent - thank you @Charlieface. Also worth noting that the 2nd example can also use ROW_NUMBER as well... although obviously that does return that column with the data

Comment: In fact, I've just checked, and so can the first!

Comment: Yes, but there is not really as much a guarantee of getting it in the right order with `ROW_NUMBER`, although this article claims that there is http://dataeducation.com/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense_rank/

Answer (score 1):

One more approach: **Pre-Computing the element's position**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(theXml XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(TheXml) VALUES(N'<d><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i></d>')
                              ,(N'<d><i>10</i><i>20</i><i>30</i><i>40</i></d>')
                              ,(N'<d><i>5</i><i>3</i><i>3</i><i>-1</i></d>')
                              ,(N'<d><i>0</i><i>1</i></d>')
                               ;

SELECT A.theIndex
      ,t.theXml.value('(/d/i[sql:column("A.theIndex")]/text())[1]','int')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(t.theXml.value(N'count(/d/i)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(theIndex);
```

The idea in short:

- We use `CROSS APPLY` to create a tally for each row separately
- We use as computed `TOP()`-clause using the row's count of `<i>`-elements
- This will create the correct count of related rows per row
- Now we can use `theIndex` to fetch the element's value by its position using `sql:column()`